# Regex of getting rid of punctuations before and after a string

Tags: java, regex, punctuation

Is there a way I can get rid of notations at the front and the end of a string?

For example,

```
"hello," -> "hello"
"hello;" -> "hello"
```

In other words, remove all punctuation after, before, or within a word, except single quotes and single dashes if they're followed by more letters.

More examples,

```
"lies,", "'This", "all-eating" and "deserv'd."
```

will become

```
"lies", "this", "all-eating" and "deserv'd"
```

Comment: `remove all punctuation after, before, or within a word` provide an example for within a word. And also don't forget to show your attempts.

Comment: "lies,", "'This", "all-eating" and "deserv'd", which go to "lies", "this", "all-eating" and "deserv'd"

Comment: What would be the expected output? Add the above comment in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the poxix regex term `\p{Punct}`:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^\\p{Punct}*|\\p{Punct}+$|\\p{Punct}{2,}", "")
```

The mid-word punctuations are removed using a "two or more" match.

---

Some test code:

```
for (String str : new String[]{"hello,", "hello;", "li--es", "'This", "all-eating", "deserv'd."})
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("^\\p{Punct}*|\\p{Punct}+$|\\p{Punct}{2,}", ""));
```

Output:

```
hello
hello
lies
This
all-eating
deserv'd
```